# create a vector of dates that follow a probability distribution

Tags: r, date, probability

I am trying to create a fake dataset for training purposes, and would like a function to create a vector of dates that matches a certain probability distribution... ie - there should be more dates from a certain range selected than another.

I know that to select a range of dates, I can do this:

`seq(as.Date("1940-12-30"), as.Date("2005-01-04"), by="days")`

And to assign to a population, I can do this:

`dchisq(x=1:500,df = 100)`  or `rlnorm(500,1,.6)`

But I'm drawing a blank on how to make the `seq()` draw from one of the specific probability distributions mentioned above. So how do I draw dates according to the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can describe what probability you want for each date, you can do this with sample.  Here is an example that samples from the days of 2005 using a Gaussian distribution centered at mid-year.

```
    Y05 = seq(as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2005-12-31"), by="days")
    Prob = dnorm((1:365)*4/365 - 2)
    sample(Y05, 10, replace=TRUE, prob=Prob)
```

Comment: A sundry point to note: probability weights in `sample()` need not add to 1, but they must be > 0

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to work around this might be to think of the problem as a general sampling problem instead of a date-sampling problem. If, for instance, you consider the problem to be selecting the offsets between some fixed date and the target dates, you've transformed the problem to a weighted integer sampling problem, and you already know how to solve that.